# Force non-null while preserving constness

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants

Consider this class

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
       : r_obj(&nullobj)
    {}

    void setDataRef(const T& obj)
    {
        r_obj = &obj;
    }

private:
    static T nullobj;
    const T* r_obj;
};
```

This forces `r_obj` to point to something, and I know that the class cannot modify the logical state of whatever it points to. However, now it is perfectly legal to pass a temporary object to `setDataRef` which is really bad.

If instead using `setDataRef(T&)`, the constness is lost.

Passing a pointer does not force the object to really point to something.

Is it possible to get all three:

- Constness
- Non-null
- Forbid temporary

Comment: Make the signature `setDataRef(const T* p)`, then it's the user's problem how they come by a pointer.

Comment: And why have a `nullobj` when you could just leave `r_obj` null?

Comment: @KerrekSB but then I may get nullptr. For the other question: Null Object Pattern [ useful to avoid `if(r_obj!=nullptr)` ... ]

Comment: You can make a copy of the `obj` parameter.

Comment: @user877329 A user passing null would be a violation of the contract of the function, that is their problem. To be helpful, you could assert on it.

Comment: @YSC, which implies a copy of the object, which may be not good.

Comment: @BoBTFish: Agreed. Asserting on a a pointer value is at least *possible*, wheras asserting on the continued lifetime of a temporary is not.

Comment: Yes, a copy generally implies a copy xD. I'm not saying it's a good solution, just that it should be considerd. After all, `std::vector::push_back()` does a copy.

Comment: BTW, passing a reference does not guarantee that it points to valid object (dangling references) or to object with [address different from 0](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eeea0b3fc6602f8e) (second one invokes UB).

Comment: Whatever you do, you should make it clear the caller has responsibility to ensure the lifetime of the referenced object. Clearly, passing a temporary is a complete failure in ensuring the lifetime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In old C++ I think this was impossible, but with C++11 we can do:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
       : r_obj(&nullobj)
    {}

    void setDataRef(const T& obj)
    {
        r_obj = &obj;
    }
    void setDataRef(T&& obj) = delete;   // Crucial extra line

private:
    static T nullobj;
    const T* r_obj;
};
```

If somebody tries to pass a temporary to `setDataRef`, overload resolution will prefer the `T&&` version but because it is deleted, the call is ill-formed.  If somebody passes an lvalue, that will bind to the const reference.

Comment: I learnt something. I always assumed in this case `setDataRef(const T& obj)`would be called. [It does not even compile :) (Demo)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f99aef5c60bc0234)

Comment: But beware; errors are still possible.  If you pass a reference to a Foo object into a function, and set the data reference to a local variable inside the function, and then return from the function - the reference will no longer be valid.

Comment: That goes without saying. C++ does not forbid the developer to purposely crash the application.

Comment: @MarinBonner The idea is that removing the possibility of passing a temporary gives a good documentation that the object must survive the function call, and the next larger scope is then the lifetime of the class.

Answer (score 4):

Martin's suggestion is very nice and does prevent the caller from passing an rvalue to the function. But that still won't guarantee that the lifetime of the passed object extends beyond the lifetime of the `Foo` instance.

If the object stores a pointer to the passed object, it would be most intuitive, if a pointer were passed to the setter. Passing a pointer also prevents using an rvalue (because taking an address of an rvalue is not allowed).

Just like you have to document the interface that the passed object must exist as long as `Foo` instance exists, you can also document that the passed pointer must not be null. Additionally, you can assert it. You could similarly delete the overload for `nullptr_t` to prevent passing the literal to the setter but that won't prevent passing null pointers of `T*` type. In my opinion, the advantage of the reference setter is not great.

Of course, neither raw pointer, nor a reference tell the caller anything about ownership, so that must in either case be documented. Instead, I would recommend storing and passing a smart pointer. `unique_ptr` if `Foo` should have the ownership (apparently not), `shared_ptr` if `Foo` should keep the object alive if it goes out of scope elsewhere, or possibly `weak_ptr` if `Foo` should have a failure mode when referred object no longer exists. A smart pointer would be self documenting and intuitive for the user.

Comment: `weak_ptr` is very interesting, because it *does* allow handling the lifetime issue.  (By always referring to nullobj if the lock fails).